# Find 2-Sylow in the group $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: group-theory

There are up to isomorphism precisely two non-abelian groups of order 8, the dihedral group
$D_4$ and $Q$ the quaternion group. $Q$ is the group whose elements are $\left\{\pm1,\pm i ,\pm j,\pm k\right\}$,
where −1 is a central element and the relations $ij = k, jk = i , ki = j , i^2 = j^2= k^2 = −1$
hold (in addition to the implicit relations such as $−1^2 = 1, −1j = −j , \ldots$ ). Prove the
following
(a) $D_4$ is not isomorphic to $Q$.

(b) $D_4$ and $Q$ are non-abelian. (Calculate, for instance what is $ji$ .)

(c) Let $P$ be the 2-Sylow subgroup of $GL_3(F_2)$. Find whether $P$ is isomorphic to $D_4$ or to $Q$.

I have this for a and b.

a) $D_4=\langle x,y:x^4=y^2=e\rangle$ has exactly two elements of order $4$, $x$ and $x^3$. $Q$  has exactly six elements of order 4, $\pm i,\pm j,\pm k$. therefore $D_4$ is not isomorphic to $Q$.

b) It is know that $Z(D_4)=\left\{e,x^2\right\}$ because $n=4$ is even. Then $D_4\neq Z(D_4)$ implies $D_4$ is non abelian. For $Q$, $ij=-ji$ therefore $Q$ no abelian.

How proves c)?
I found an overall result in [http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2013-06-24-SylowsOfGL3.pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Ejack/2013-06-24-SylowsOfGL3.pdf) but can't quite understand it, other than exceeding the question level.

Comment: One Sylow $2$-subgroup in your group consists of the matrices $\pmatrix{1&*&*\\0&1&*\\0&0&1}$. So what is that? How many elements of order $2$ has it?

Comment: More than 2 therefore $P$ 2-Sylow is isomorphic to $D_4$